# What is an efficient way to splice one binary input into another at an arbitrary bit number using Java without relying on parseInt?

Tags: java, parsing, binary

I am trying make a function in Java to splice one binary input into another using Java at the bit level as opposed to a byte level. For example splicing "00000000" into "11111111" a position 3 would produce "1110000000011111".

I have tried looking into the [JBBP library](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser) for dealing with binary data but it is almost as though there is a special coding language, other than java, which seems to be specific to this library which you write then pass as a string in Java to the `JBBPParser.prepare()` function. I tried looking in the java docs for the library but they only describe what the function does, not what the commands you can pass as a sting are, what those commands do, or what the proper syntax for those commands is.

Can anyone provide a link to the documentation for the commands you can pass as strings to the `JBBPParser` functions or provide an alternative way to splice binary data together at an arbitrary bit without relying on binary strings and parseInt as they are inefficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  Java is big-endian.  This means that your example is wrong.  Instead of inserting the zero string (00000000) after position 3 in the target byte, your example demonstrates inserting the zero string either after position 6 or before position 5 (see bit numbering below).

The operation you are looking for is called "left shift".  Here is a link discussing [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Here is the strategy you want to use:

1. Determine how many bits to shift from the target into the destination.  I will call this the `initialShiftCount`.  In your example, the initialShiftCount is 3 bits.
2. Left shift the initialShiftCount number of bits into the destination.
3. Left shift all 8 bits from the insert string into the destination.
4. Left shift the remaining bits from the target into the destination.

Terms:
*destination* - the location into which you want to place the combination of the bits in the insert string and the target.  In your example, this is the variable that ends up holding the string `1110000000011111'.<br/>
*insert string* - the bits you want to insert into the target bits.  In your example, the insert string is`00000000`.<br/>
*target* - the bits into which you want to insert the insert string.  In your example, the target is`11111111`.

**Bit Numbering**
In a big-endian system, the bits are numbered as follows: 87654321

Comment: Thank you. That is really helpful. Would this work with large data structures? Say a 128 Byte (not bit) array? I know that some languages cast data to an int before bit shifts.

Comment: The shift operator only works with primitive types.  You could do shifting in a 128 byte array, but you would have to shift each byte in a loop.